# Using UEFI to access CPU features which are locked in BIOS

Tags: bios, uefi, cpu-architecture

I have Dell Latitude E6420 with SandyBridge i5-2520M and standard issue Dell BIOS (version A15). In certain situations computer produces annoying high-pitched noise (it is not loud but it is noticeable). I know this issue is related to CPU entering certain power-saving modes (C-states). On my previous computer (Latitude E6410) it was possible to prevent CPU from entering deeper C-states (using ThrottleStop utility). Unfortunately, this is not possible with my current notebook as the feature is locked, probably in BIOS. MSR registry governing C-States (MSR_PKG_CST_CONFIG_CONTROL) cannot be altered and I am getting "General Protection Fault" when trying to do so.

1. Is it possible to use UEFI instead of BIOS to make currently locked CPU features acessible?
2. <strike>How are UEFI and BIOS related to each other?</strike>In computer architecture stack is UEFI **over** the BIOS (so the limitations set by BIOS are obligatoty for UEFI) or **beside** BIOS (UEFI is not limited by BIOS)?

Comment: Question 2, possible duplicate...http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi

Comment: Did you call Dell warranty support to report the issue?

Comment: Thanks for duplicity warning, corrected. I found Dell warranty support feedback from previous interaction with another user reporting the same problem: http://support.euro.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=cz&cs=RC1077788&l=cs&s=gen&docid=DSN_0A7D5CD2E17F5125E0401E0A55176204&isLegacy=true (I did my googling homework before asking). Unfortunately, this is the flaw of previous Core-i CPUs I hoped SandyBridge would resolve.

Comment: Unfortunately the workaround suggested by Dell is not an option for me as my ntb lacks bluetooth module.