# Windows 8 Tails Uefi to legacy and legacy to uefi

Tags: windows-8, bios, uefi

Recently I downloaded tails os, and want to boot it from usb stick. My pc is running in uefi mode, and I heard that it's possible that windows 8.1 won't work after changing to legacy. How can I determine what's going to happen in my case, and if it won't work in legacy, will switching bios settings to uefi back make it work?

Comment: I have pre installed win8.1 on hp laptop

Comment: Just disable secure boot.  All Windows 8.1 devices are required to allow the user to disable secure boot.  You shouldn't have to switch to legacy mode, and you are right, if you do then that requires you to reinstall Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8 and 8.1 will work regardless of if you're running in Legacy or UEFI mode. If you're interested, you can check which BIOS mode your computer is running in by following [these](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/29504-bios-mode-see-if-windows-boot-uefi-legacy-mode.html) instructions. You can learn about the differences between UEFI and Legacy BIOS modes by going to [this superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi) thread.

I think what you probably want to research, based on your question, is [Secure Boot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481258.aspx), which uses a UEFI to "...make sure that your PC boots using only firmware that is trusted by the manufacturer." If you're interested in disabling Secure Boot on your HP laptop, follow Option Three of [these](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/17058-secure-boot-enable-disable-uefi.html) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Once Windows is installed in EFI mode, booting it in BIOS mode requires significant reconfiguration, and vice-versa; however, doing a one-time boot from an external medium should not cause disruption to your Windows installation, no matter what the external medium's boot mode. Note that in this context, you can repeat a "one-time boot" as often as you like; it's not as if the second or third boot will suddenly mess everything up.

That said, if you need to boot something in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, you may need to adjust your firmware's settings. In particular, you may need to [disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) and/or enable your BIOS/CSM/legacy support. Unfortunately, the details of how to do these things vary from one machine to another. On some computers, enabling BIOS/CSM/legacy support may interfere with EFI-mode booting, but the change should be easily reversible.

I'm not all *that* familiar with Tails, but I seem to recall hearing of people booting it in EFI mode. This might entail adding an EFI-mode boot loader to the medium, but it can probably be done if you want to -- even with Secure Boot active, if you [jump through the right hoops.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) Such a customization might be worth investigating, particularly if you find you need to adjust firmware options each time you switch what you want to boot.