# My bios is not showing up on bootup

Tags: windows-8, uefi

My Windows 7 was crashed so I tried to to boot windows 8 from USB pendrive and in EFI settings I went to advanced tab and in that I just selected (USB-name)UEFI boot and then my laptop restarted automatically after that now the problem is laptop is not showing the firmware or splash screen and it gets stuck there and I don't even know if the operating system is getting booted. Does anyone knows what kind of problem it might be ? Any suggestions ?

```
Laptops: Asus K55VM 
BIOS: Aptio
```

Comment: what happens when you remove the usb and while trying to boot normally?also refer here http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi

Comment: Nothing happens, My laptop heats up seems like some heavy process is running. Should I flash my rom ? also is there any way I can reset my rom without flashing it ? @BlueBerry-vignesh4303