# Windows Server / Windows 10 installer won't boot

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2

My friend gave me a [HP ProLiant ML310 Generation 3 (G3)](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04284178.pdf?ver=21) server a while ago. All went good until I tried to install Windows Server 2012 R2, and after that Windows 10.

The Windows server installer just gets stuck in a **boot loop**. The Windows 10 installer gets **stuck** at the logo without the loading indicator.

CentOS installs fine, and I haven't tried it yet, but I think Ubuntu will install fine as well. My friend thinks its something to do with UEFI or EFI partitioning or something like that.

**Why won't the Windows installers boot?**

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the older HP G3 Servers do not support UEFI booting, which windows 10 and server 2012 R2 use.  You could try to look for some settings in the BIOS about EFI or UEFI, or even update the BIOS to the latest version... may help.

To see the difference between BIOS and UEFI have a look at this article
[What is the difference in "Boot with BIOS" and "Boot with UEFI"](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)