# EFI and GRUB2 where to get binaries and how to mount the boot system

Tags: multi-boot, operating-systems, grub2, efi

UEFI and GRUB2

Anybody knows the site to get the binaries
(bootia32.efi and bootx64.efi) to boot grub2...
also the GRUB2 binaries... and a good tutorial help on this...

I want to make a multi-boot disk something like this...

```
EFI
    \BOOT
        \bootia32.efi
        \bootx64.efi
        \<grub-binaries>
        \<grub-background-image>
        \<grub-configuration-file>

    \AndroidX86v6
    \Microsoft
    \Ubuntu
    \Tails
    \Kali
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names `bootx64.efi` and `bootia32.efi` refer to the EFI fallback boot loader program. This program can be *anything* -- GRUB, the Windows boot loader, an EFI shell, malware, etc. Thus, you should not search for a program by that name; rather, you should search for a program by its actual name (GRUB in your question) and rename it to `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` or `EFI\BOOT\bootia32.efi` (depending on platform) on your boot medium. In fact, if you're installing to a computer's internal hard disk, you probably shouldn't use that name at all -- instead, you should rely on the EFI's own built-in boot manager to remember the name of the binary you want to launch. (An exception would be if your firmware is badly broken, as some still are.) The `boot{arch}.efi` filenames were originally intended exclusively for use on bootable removable disks, such as for OS installers and emergency recovery tools; but they're also used for boot loaders of last resort on internal hard disks -- say, for when the NVRAM entries have been damaged.

As to the main part of your question, GRUB binaries tend to be built by and for individual distributions; AFAIK, there is no official source for "the" GRUB binary for EFI. The usual way to obtain *a* GRUB binary is to install a Linux distribution that uses it. It will normally be installed as `/boot/efi/EFI/{distname}/grubx64.efi`, where `{distname}` is a code used by the distribution, such as `ubuntu` for Ubuntu or `fedora` for Fedora. Note, however, that simply moving and renaming this binary might not work, since it may have hard-coded paths to its configuration file. If the target computer uses Secure Boot, too, you'll need to rename the `shimx64.efi` or `shim.efi` file as the fallback filename and copy `grubx64.efi`, using that name, to the same directory as Shim. If you're installing to one computer, you shouldn't need to bother with moving or renaming GRUB; just install normally and it should take over the boot process -- at least, until you install the next distribution or something reconfigures the boot order.

For a system with multiple Linux distributions, GRUB can be a bit cumbersome. This is because GRUB relies on a complex configuration file to create its menu of boot options, and that configuration file is maintained within the distribution that installed GRUB. This works OK when you install just one Linux distribution, but with several distributions, you must update GRUB in the distribution from which it came in order to present new kernels installed from your *other* distributions. The alternative is to chainload one GRUB from another, which may work better, but is more cumbersome at boot time.

Another approach is to use a boot manager that involves less complex configuration. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can do this; it detects Linux kernels on each boot, so once it's set up, it can boot the latest kernel without changes to its own configuration. Other boot loaders, like SYSLINUX and ELILO, require GRUB-style configuration in a centralized configuration file, but that file is simpler and therefore easier to maintain by hand. If you use any of these tools on a removable disk, you'll need to copy it to the `boot{arch}.efi` filename.

There are numerous other caveats and quirks to all of this, but without knowing more about your intended use and hardware, I can't go into them all here without writing a small book. You might want to check out one or more of the following sites for more information:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog.
- **[My page on EFI boot loaders for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/index.html)** -- This page describes EFI boot loader choices for Linux systems.

Comment: I'm building a boot disk and used the SuperGrubDisk project download to  get the binaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to use grub to UEFI PXE boot or UEFI HTTP boot, you get the prebuilt binaries here without any installation:
https://images.maas.io/ephemeral-v3/stable/bootloaders/uefi/amd64/20230222.0/

```
shim-signed.tar.xz
grub2-signed.tar.xz
```

Decompress them, you will get

```
bootx64.efi
grubx64.efi
```

Then you prepare a TFTP server and HTTP server to serve them, and prepare grub/grub.cfg via TFTP/HTTP.

I have been using above way successfully.

There are also another convenient place let you get them without any installation.
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/

(you can change the jammy to focal or bionic)

```
...
grubnetx64.efi
grubnetx64.efi.signed
grubx64.efi
grubx64.efi.signed
```

I have not tried it, I guess the `grubnetx64.efi.signed` means net version of `grubx64.efi.signed`. But I am not clear about the diff of *.efi.signed and *.efi.

And the bootx64.efi can be found here
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/signed/shim-amd64/current/, just rename the decompressed file to bootx64.efi.