# Unable to install windows 10 on my new laptop (with DOS) from UEFI( SOLVED)

Tags: windows, usb, uefi

As clear from the topic i bought a new laptop yesterday . Acer aspire e15 575g- 51va.

**INFO**

It came with dos pre-installed and i want to install windows 10 on it. so i used my old laptop(lenovo e49) to make a bootable usb drive using rufus tool.

However my old laptop had a traditional bios whereas my new laptop has something called UEFI(i found out about it after i looked up on the web for solutions).

Now i used fat32( file systme for the usb drive) and gpt partition for uefi (for partition scheme and target system type).

**ERROR-**

However after i insert the disk and boot from it , it gave me the error "your pc needs to be repaired. a required device is not connected or can't be accessed. error code:0xc000000f"(for windows 10) "boot configuration data for your pc is missing or contains errors"(for windows 7).

**WHAT I TRIED**

Now i tried to use the same usb drive in my old laptop from bios but whenever i click on the USB drive from 'temporary startup device ' in bios it does nothing and brings the same startup device list again.

**MY PROBLEM-**

Now i don't understand if my old laptop is a problem or there is a problem in my new one.

I fail to understand the how could my new laptop with ms-dos have problems and i searched through the internet for solutions.

All i found out is that i need a windows installation media and boot from it and then select repair my computer .

But i don't have any any other windows installation media ; otherwise i would have used that for installing windows in the first place.i don't even have windows installed and still gave me this error on my new laptop.

Comment: If your laptop came preinstalled with DOS you need to buy a Windows licence.

Comment: Which options in rufus did you use, and what iso did you start with?

Comment: I didn't know they still sold DOS...

Comment: i used fat32 file system and gpt for uefi option . i used windows 10 pro iso.

Comment: @Burgi several laptops in India come with Freedos out of the box

Comment: Do you want to dual-boot with DOS or replace DOS with Windows? If the former, you'll have to install Windows in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, since AFAIK DOS doesn't support EFI-mode booting. If the latter, you could install Windows in BIOS mode or in EFI/UEFI mode, but the latter will require converting the disk from MBR to GPT and perhaps adjusting firmware settings. Your Windows installation medium is probably EFI-only, given the way you prepared it. See [this question and answer](http://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi) for background info.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem.I found out that the problem was neither in my old laptop nor in my new one. everything except rufus .

I made a bootable drive with windows USB DVD download tool and that worked . However when i booted up (also i used legacy mode because UEFI was giving the same error again and again), there was another error.

The installer didn't allow me to select any of the hard drive partitions to install windows .

It said my partition were in gpt format and were incompatible. So i ran command prompt from recovery settings in installer and converted my GPT partition into MBR and everything worked flawlessly .