# Is using legacy mode instead of UEFI mode a bad thing to do?

Tags: linux, installation

Can using legacy mode instead of UEFI mode affect my laptop in any way?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/496026/893950

Comment: I did this by accident for somewhere around 5 months. Everything worked fine, the only issue occurred when I needed to reinstall and, when I switched back, UEFI didn't recognize the disk with the legacy boot files.

Answer (score 21):

It won't cause any damage.

Legacy mode (a.k.a. BIOS mode, CSM boot) matters only when the operating system boots. Once it boots, it doesn't matter anymore. If everything works as expected and you're happy with it, legacy mode is fine.

Advantages of UEFI boot include:

- **Faster boot times**. UEFI can skip initialization of some devices which would be reinitialized by OS anyway
- Optional **extra security**. You can enable Secure Boot, which checks digital signatures of OS components, ensuring that they weren't tampered with. You should combine it with BIOS password protection.
- If you're using multiple OSes, UEFI offers **boot manager integrated into firmware**.
- If you're using Windows, UEFI mode lets you use GPT partitioning scheme, which supports **disks over 3 TB**. (Linux can use GPT without UEFI)

Comment: great general answer  - you may want to add one exception - legacy mode (sometimes?) disables TPM which can negatively impact the ability to do full disk encryption.

Comment: "UEFI offers boot manager integrated into firmware" only if said firmware properly implement the boot order part of the UEFI spec, and quite a few don't (i.e. always boot Windows' `bootmgfw.efi`). Laptop firmware are notable repeat offenders. Whether or not the user has access to an interactive boot menu on top of that is yet another story.

Comment: *(...) matters only when operating system boots. Once it boots, it doesn't matter anymore.* - Well, that's not entirely accurate.

Comment: @davidgo All I have are legacy systems here and they have TPM in their BIOSes that enable without any issue and I can do full drive encryptions without problems.

Comment: @Terrance FDE is perfectly possible without TPM, are you sure you're using it?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm actually not using it.  But the point was that I don't have UEFI BIOSes on either of my systems and TPM is there and fully capable of being enabled.  At work, I use Legacy on the Dell tower on my desk and I use FDE no issue since it is a work requirement for us to have it.

Comment: @Terrance Are they actually BIOS-based and not just UEFIs running in legacy mode? Original TPM spec was released in 2009 when the industry was switching to UEFI already, if there are any BIOS systems with TPM they're about 10 years old at this point.

Comment: @gronostaj Nope, I have a MSI MS-7508 (K9N2GM-FIH) motherboard that is still in use in my server that was released in 2008 that does not have a UEFI BIOS at all on it but it does indeed have TPM Support in the BIOS.

Answer (score 7):

Is it bad? Not at all. Switching to legacy mode might confuse or break a bootloader that expects UEFI, but you can always switch back if you aren't able to boot. Nothing will be permanently changed which cannot be undone. You will, of course, lose UEFI-specific features like Secure Boot, custom UEFI modules, and the ability to [disable early PCI DMA](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/54433.html) for security.

Original BIOSes were quite simple. They initialized hardware, set up [BIOS functions](https://wiki.osdev.org/BIOS#BIOS_functions) that could be called while in real (or [VM86](https://wiki.osdev.org/Virtual_8086_Mode)) mode, copied the first sector from the primary storage device, the [MBR](https://wiki.osdev.org/MBR), to address 0x7C00 and executed it. The BIOS itself remained in the first page of memory where it held components (such as the [IVT](https://wiki.osdev.org/IVT) and [BDA](https://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)#BIOS_Data_Area_.28BDA.29)) that were needed if returning to real mode.

Modern UEFI systems are significantly more complex and do a *lot* more under the hood. However, some operating systems expect BIOS behavior and won't work with UEFI. The solution is CSM mode, or legacy mode, where a UEFI module is loaded that exposes itself to the operating system like a genuine BIOS, allowing compatibility with systems that require legacy BIOS features.

The operating system doesn't need to be aware of UEFI-specific behavior the firmware is running in CSM mode. See [OSDev's page on UEFI](https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI) for more information.

Comment: I installed Linux on my notebook in legacy mode (because I didn't know what I was doing with UEFI) and ended up with a dead Windows 10 partition that won't boot any more. This turned out to be more of a plus in my situation ;) , but if you need dual boot ...

Answer (score 0):

I have used both types thousands of times literally! As a senior tech for law enforcement, public and private institutions of higher learning, and private and public schools. I can tell you its a matter of the age of your machine. Some machines fully support it (newer), and some barely support it (several years old), and some older machines never had it or should have never had it! It offers speedier boot times and some added security for your machines, if you have survived this long on a legacy machine stick with it, it wont hurt. If you have important data that can cause great harm to you or your institution if your machine is stolen then I would switch to UEFI mode and implement the added security it can provide. A few of the others have described some of the things that can be done.

Comment: _"If you have important data that can cause great harm to you or your institution if your machine is stolen then I would switch to UEFI mode and implement the added security it can provide"_ - can you elaborate on security benefits of UEFI?