# Duplicate partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

Does anyone think there is a problem with below partitioning? I haven't done it myself and I can see that partitions 0 & 4 are the same. I am having a hard time figuring out why it appears twice and what having 3 primary partitions mean. My hard drive is a 500GB HDD.

```
Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
-------------  ----------------  -------  -------
Partition 1    Primary            500 MB  1024 KB
Partition 2    Primary            148 GB   501 MB
Partition 3    Primary            151 GB   148 GB
Partition 0    Extended           165 GB   300 GB
Partition 4    Logical            165 GB   300 GB
```

Comment: It may be helpful for future reference to include the partition information from the image into your question marked up with code formatting.

Comment: Done. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard for MBR partitioning scheme.

MBR scheme was originally limited to 4 partitions. This limitation turned out to be inconvenient, so a workaround was invented: you can turn one of 4 *primary* partitions into an *extended* partition. This partition can't contain data directly, but it can hold an unlimited number of *logical disks*.

You have three primary partitions and an extended partition containing a single logical disk, which takes up entire extended partition.

MBR is a bit dated and was since superseded by GPT, but if you don't need UEFI boot (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1449092/194694) for a list of benefits) it's fine.