# RHEL + how comes EFI boot partition created when we install RHEL 7.9 version from scratch

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, redhat-enterprise-linux

We are using servers as `DELL R630` in our lab's, when OS version is RHEL 7.9.

Here is an example from filesystem on these servers (from boot point of view):

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  500G  0 disk
├─sda1               8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2               8:2    0  229G  0 part
```

Recently we get new DELL servers as R750, and we also installed the RHEL 7.9 from the same ISO on that servers.

Now we have additional boot partition - `/boot/efi`.

```
lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0   500G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2             8:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3             8:3    0   560G  0 part
```

From `fstab` its looks like this:

```
UUID=746E-8398          /boot/efi               vfat    defaults,uid=0,gid=0,umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
```

Since we are using the same ISO file for installing RHEL 7.9 from the same ISO, on all type of servers, then we do not understand how comes we get the new partition `/boot/efi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you boot the installer in UEFI mode then it will use (create if needed) an [EFI system partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition); but if you boot in [BIOS (legacy) mode](https://superuser.com/q/1449092/432690) then it won't.

The mount point for the EFI system partition is usually `/boot/efi`, like in your case.

It so happens [in R630 *Boot Mode* is set to *BIOS* by default](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/poweredge-r630-dsms/r630_om_pub/boot-settings-details?guid=guid-2f825dc7-a22a-482f-bbec-c2c19fe78781&lang=en-us&lwp=rt), while [in R750 it's *UEFI* by default](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-uk/poweredge-r750/per750_bios_pub_ism/boot-settings?guid=guid-0fa8016c-1c07-4d25-92e9-117d4fe10269&lang=en-us). It looks like the default mode was used for every server. This explains the difference.

Do not miss this warning:

> CAUTION Switching the boot mode may prevent the system from booting if the operating system is not installed in the same boot mode.

If I were you, I would leave it as-is.

Comment: @KingDavid - So reinstall RHEL in BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode on the newer server.

Comment: sorry but still not clear if on R750 server we can switch between /boot or /boot/efi , in other words can we install the RHEL with /boot on R750 ?  and not the /boot/efi ,

Comment: @KingDavid I think you can, but please read the linked manual. E.g. it states "You must use only the UEFI boot mode in order to boot from NVMe drives". There may be other limitations.